# App Crashing When Replacing Fragment Before WebView Loads

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview

My app uses a navigation drawer and replaces the fragment on my main activity when a selection is made in the drawer. I have a couple of fragments that show a web view. The problem occurs if I open the drawer and select a different item , thus replacing the fragment with the web view, before the page in the webview has finished loading. When this happens, I get this error:

```
12-02 08:07:48.605  11745-11745/kyfb.android.kyfb.com.kyfb A/chromium﹕ [FATAL:jni_android.cc(271)] Check failed: false.
12-02 08:07:48.605  11745-11745/kyfb.android.kyfb.com.kyfb A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 11745 (d.kyfb.com.kyfb)
```

Here is one of the fragments with a webview.

```
public class AnnualMeetingFragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView web;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    private String url;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ag_facts, null);

        url = "http://www.kyfbnewsroom.com/2013-kentucky-farm-bureau-annual-meeting-program/";

        web = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.web);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.prgPageLoading);

        web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        web.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        web.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        web.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);

        web.loadUrl(url);

        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView webView, int progress) {
                getActivity().setProgress(progress * 100);
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });

        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(web, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(web, url);
                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {


                if(url.endsWith(".mp4") || url.endsWith(".3gp") || url.endsWith(".avi") || url.endsWith(".flv")){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i); //warning no error handling will cause force close if no media player on phone.
                    return true;
                }

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: webview is a fragment ?

Comment: Can you give code for us with your webView?

Comment: What happens when you remove `super.onCreateView(...)`?

Comment: @Randy, removing it doesn't seem to change it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why are you getting this error, i think it should be something like NullPointerException.
Try next:
Evert time you calling `getActivity()` on Fragment instance you should be sure, that fragment is actually have this Activity. Because when your webview is loading you are calling this function:

```
web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView webView, int progress) {
            getActivity().setProgress(progress * 100);
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    });
```

I thing you should replace all your code where you are calling `getActivity()` on something like this:

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
if (activity != null) {
    // do something
}
```

Try this and tell me if this work.

Comment: If it was a NullPointerException the stacktrace would say NullPonterException. The fatal signal is related to something happening in the WebView. It may have something to do with the state of the webview when calling a certain function. For example see my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18755318/webview-destroy-causing-fatal-signal-11-crash). I had a fatal signal when calling `WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData()` after destroying all WebViews. My guess is this guy has a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should destroy the webview when the fragment is detached.

Call the webview.destroy()  from the fragment's on detached method.

Answer (score 0):

The FragmentManager may be holding on to old fragments that you can retrieve by a tag key.
Go into your activity that has the FragmentManager that is doing the replace.
When doing the replace, use a tag to identify the fragment.  Before you do the replace, check if the fragment manager already has a fragment with that tag and use that one instead of creating a new fragment instance.  Your fragment transaction should look something like this:

```
String fragTag = "FRAGMENT_1"; //Should be a class constant 
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(fragTag);
if(fragment == null) {
    fragment = new AnnualMeetingFragment();
}
ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragTag);
ft.commit();
```

Also, "onReceivedError" in your WebViewClient implementation may happen when the Fragment is not actually attached to an activity.  So getActivity() may not be returning a valid value there.